# How to mock "new" created objects inside a method in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-test-fixtures

I have a legacy code where the code looks like below :

```
public String getToken() {

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(endpoint).getConnection();
..
}
```

How to mock a `new URL(endpoint).getConnection()`. Until I get a mocked `urlConnection`, I can't proceed into further statements of the method.

Comment: You can't. What you've identified is a problem with the design of the code - it's tightly coupled to a concrete implemenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock this piece of code. Why?

Let's say you mocked the URL object but when the code reaches this part of the code, `new URL(endpoint)` the new URL object is always created.

This is a bad design and the best thing you can possibly do is to inject the object into the constructor which makes the code easily testable as you can mock it.